# CKEditor - unable to use any plugin

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, ckeditor, sharepoint-online

I tried to add plugin for color picker in CKEditor5 (React with Typescript app - loaded on Sharepoint site), but for any plugin that I add I get following error in console:

```
  DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "hex-color-picker" has already been used with this registry
```

I don't have anything custom that defined hex-color-picker already.

Code:

```
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { Bold } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles';



<CKEditor
       editor={ ClassicEditor }
       config={{
        extraPlugins: [this.uploadPlugin],
        plugins: [Bold]
       }}
       data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
       onReady={ editor => {             
        console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
       } }
       onChange={ (event, editor) => {
        const data = editor.getData();
        console.log({ event, editor, data });
        } }
      />
```

package.json

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^38.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^6.0.0",
```

Can I do anything about it?

Comment: is `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles` version the same as `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic`? And instead of importing `import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'` try `import { ClassicEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic'`